# Brother MFC + Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, all-in-one, brother-printer

I'm using Windows 7 **64bit** (RTM version).

I bought myself a new Brother MFC6490CW but I'm having troubles with installing the drivers.

When I set compatibility to Windows Vista Service Pack 2 I can only install the scanner functionality from the Brother Solution Center and not the printer driver:

Printer (driver) FAILED FAILED
Scanner (driver) Installed Connected
PC-FAX send FAILED FAILED
PC-FAX receive Installed Connected
Remote Setup Installed Connected

Anybody who has a fix for this? The brother drivers for windows 7 will be released at the end of October  and I can't wait so long. Need my printer..

Tnx in advance.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Brother%20MFC-7440N%20All-in-One%20Printer&v=Brother&uid=&pf=12&pi=7&c=Printers%20%26%20Scanners&sc=Multifunction&os=32-bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the driver printers for Vista, they're entirely compatible.

I searched on brother.com and didn't find your exact model number. The model I found was MFC-6490CW, and the drivers are located [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/download_index.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc6490cw_all&type2=1&os=84&flang=English&dlid=). I hope that your model is compatible with this.

The "Full Driver & Software Package" dates from 03/04/2009, while the "WHQL certified Printer Driver & Scanner Driver" dates only from 10/20/2008. You might compare these dates to the driver you're using (using Device Manager). If your driver is earlier, or is a Microsoft-generic, you might replace it with this one.

But first see if Windows Update doesn't find an optional update for your printer.

And don't forget to create a system restore point before starting these manipulations.

Comment: Agreed - I have the MFC 6490CW sitting right next to me, connected via network.  Prints and Scans just fine (don't use faxing).

Comment: The vista drivers caused some trouble in Windows 7 x64.
The updates came with Windows Update, the drivers were not finished for Windows 7 at the time I was posting this question.
So far everything works fine.